# How can I remove certain elements of a query string?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script, where you pass it a url like `/search?filter1=question-1&filter2=question2`, and when either question-1 or question-2 is changed, it will take the url, and replace the `question-x` with the question value.

One thing I want to build in, is if the value is empty, I want it to remove the query string part. So for example, if question-1 has a value of `something`, but 2 doesn't have a value yet, the url will be `/search?filter1=something`.

What I thought would work would be something like this

```
$url.match('/([^?&]*)' + name.toSearch + '/g') // toSearch is a value like question-1
```

But that returns null. Can anybody help me figure out what I need to change to get the output I'm after?

Comment: You can explode the querystring, find the variables you expect to find, then reassemble it with those variables so as to leave off empty parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the url /search?filter=question-1, I need to see if the element with the name question[1] has a value, if it does, replace question-1 with the value, and if it doesn't have one, remove the total filter=question-1 string.

Knowing your requirements better from the comments, I completely rewrote my answer using parts of my original answer and some of your code:

```
// Given url
var url = '/search?filter1=question-1&filter2=question-2';

// Specify the filters so no extra query string noise enters the final url
var filters = ["filter1", "filter2", "filter3"];

// Split the query string parts
var urlParts = url.split(/([&?])/);
var reassembled = [];

// Break the url parts into key:value pairs
var qs = (function(a) {
  if (a === "") return {};
  var b = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
  {
    var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
    if (p.length == 1)
      b[p[0]] = "";
    else
      b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  return b;
})(urlParts);

// This include a param:value in the reassembled array
function includeQSParam(param, value) {
  if(qs[param]) {
    reassembled.push(param + "=" + value);
  }
}

// Run through the filters
for(var ind in filters) {
  var filter = filters[ind];

  // Check that the filter exists and the supplied value is of type question-
  if(qs[filter] && qs[filter].indexOf("question-") >= 0) {
    // Turns question-number into question[number] so it's a valid selector.
    var inputSelector = "question["+(qs[filter]).replace(/\D/g, "")+"]";  

    // Get the input, and the value (author-supplied code)
    var $input = $('[name="' + inputSelector + '"]');

    // TODO: confirm this is how you get the value
    var value = $input.closest('.question').val();

    if($input.length > 0 && (value !== '' && value !== undefined)) {

      // Replace the parameter's original value with the question value
      includeQSParam(filter, value);
    } else {
      // Nothing to do. This filter will be removed automatically
    }
  }
}

// Reassemble the URL
var fixedUrl = urlParts[0] + (reassembled.length > 0 ? "?"+reassembled.join("&") : "");
```

Again, this was reworked from my original answer so there will be some bloat, but I didn't want to abandon the question on you.

Comment: Thanks for that, that was 99% of the way there. I tweaked it around a little to fit my use, but it's must better than what I had. Here's what I ended up with. http://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/a7grj61k/

Comment: @TomHart Ah, very nice. It looks like it works well with your supplied HTML. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Drakes answer is a good one, it didn't quite fit into my needs. I've ended up with this, which works well so far, but I'm still testing it.

```
var $url = '/search?filter1=question-1&filter2=question-2';

// Break the url into parts.
var $split = $url.split(/([&?])/);

$.each($split, function(indexToRemove, part){

    // If the part is a question.
    if(typeof part == 'string' && part.indexOf('question-') > -1){

        var $number = part.split('=');

        // Turns question-number into question[number] so it's a valid selector.
        $inputSelector = String($number[1]).replace('-', '[') + ']';

        // Get the input, and the value.
        var $input = $('[name="' + $inputSelector + '"]');
        var $value = getValue($input.closest('.question'));



        // If there is an element, and there is a value.
        if($input.length > 0 && ($value != '' && $value != undefined)){

            $split[indexToRemove] = part.replace($number[1], $value);
        } else {

            $split.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
        }
    }
});


$url = $split.join('');

// If for example question-1 has a value of 'Test', and question-2 has no value, $url will now be '/search?filter1=Test'.
```

Comment: Please don't be shy about further specifying your requirements. I put effort into this answer, so I can adjust it for you.

Comment: Okay, basically, given the url `/search?filter=question-1`, I need to see if the element with the name `question[1]` has a value, if it does, replace `question-1` with the value, and if it doesn't have one, remove the total `filter=question-1` string.

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer using parts of my original answer and some of your code to complete my answer. It works in my tests. I didn't want to abandon the question on you.